# Excel index match 2 criteria

Tags: excel-formula, match, conditional-statements

I am trying to get Excel to return ReturnNo if 2 conditions are met. So far I have:

`=Index(ReturnNo;Match(Name;Name2Array;0)`

`=Index(ReturnNo;Match(City;City2Array;0)`

I don´t know how to combine these 2 formulas so that ReturnNo is only returned if both are true. 
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Are there ever any duplicates? ie: is there any time that there are multiple items which match both the Name and the City?

Comment: Sometimes there are duplicates for both the Name and the City, however most of the time there is a duplicate for either the Name or the city. Since there are not too many duplicates, I think I will check them manually. Thanks for your help! (PS I didn´t think the solution would be that simple: adding  &...)

Comment: If this answer was helpful please mark my answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates, and Name2Array & City2Array are all text, simply do:

```
=Index(ReturnNo;Match(Name&City;Name2Array&City2Array;0))
```

This is an array formula; when it is typed you must confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER. Here's some background discussion on array formulas: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/2011-03-23-excel-2010-multi-cell-array-formula-sbs-tutorial.htm